# How clear App Fabric Cache one time a day?

Tags: c#, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I look for a configuration for clear cache each day at midnight.

It is possible ?

Or I need create a schedule task and clear in a code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// My cache, handle it the way you like
private static DataCache _cache;

public static void ClearCache()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(_cache.GetSystemRegions(), region =>
    {
         _cache.ClearRegion(region);
         var sysRegion = _cache.GetSystemRegionName(region);
         _cache.ClearRegion(sysRegion);
     });
 }
```

Then run this at some schedule which you define yourself, somewhere.

I suppose the equivalent is fully possible to do in Powershell too, but this is a solution I've been using for a while.